# Adding an element to a VP tree (VP tree maintenance)

Tags: search, tree, binary-search-tree, similarity, approximate-nn-searching

I have read few sources on VP-tree for similarity knn.
No one wrote about adding an element to exists tree, which is required for maintenance.
Explanation of adding element will be just great.

Comment: Are you going to say something for the answer or should I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

```
add

public boolean add(E point)

Adds a single point to this vp-tree. Addition of a point executes in O(log n) time in the best case (where n is the number of points in the tree), but may also trigger a node partition that takes additional time.

Specified by:
    add in interface Collection<E extends GeospatialPoint>
Parameters:
    point - the point to add to this tree
Returns:
    true if the tree was modified by the addition of this point; vp-trees are always modified by adding points, so this method always returns true

addAll

public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> points)

Adds all of the points in the given collection to this vp-tree.

Specified by:
    addAll in interface Collection<E extends GeospatialPoint>
Parameters:
    points - the points to add to this tree
Returns:
    true if the tree was modified by the addition of the points; vp-trees are always modified by adding points, so this method always returns true
```

The interface comes from [VPTree (jeospatial)](http://jchambers.github.io/jeospatial/javadoc/com/eatthepath/jeospatial/vptree/VPTree.html#add%28E%29).

So, the best you could do is to contact the authors and/or search for the algorithm somewhere [here](https://github.com/jchambers/jeospatial/blob/master/test/com/eatthepath/jeospatial/vptree/TreeIteratorTest.java).

---

You understand I hope that this is too broad for SO, thus the answer is mostly a linked-one.